# How can I make squares?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics, box2d, polygon

I'm trying to generate random, convex, non-self-intersecting polygons - quadrilaterals specifically.

I've gotten as far as:

```
function randquad(){

          var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef,
              fixDef = new b2FixtureDef,
              x=0, y=0;

          fixDef.density = Math.random();
          fixDef.friction = Math.random();
          fixDef.restitution = Math.random()*0.3;

          bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
          fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
          fixDef.shape.SetAsArray([
            new b2Vec2(x, y),
            new b2Vec2(x+=Math.random()*2, y+=Math.random()*2*(Math.random()<0.5?1:-1)),
            new b2Vec2(x+=Math.random()*2*(Math.random()<0.5?1:-1), y+=Math.random()*2),
            new b2Vec2(x-=Math.random()*2, y+=Math.random()*2*(Math.random()<0.5?1:-1))
          ]);
          bodyDef.position.x = Math.random() * 10;
          bodyDef.position.y = 0;
          world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
        }
```

I'm working with Box2D web; however, this question is not limited to it, or javascript - its a broader one that is more mathematical.

I want to get 4 points that, in a sequence, make the shape I'm looking for.

With the code I've written I often get the desired shape; however, I do still get self-intersecting shapes. At the moment I'm not too fussed about the shapes being convex.

The reason I need such shapes is because it seems they're the only ones box2d web likes.

Any 4 points can make a non-self-intersecting quadrilateral right?
Should I generate 4 initially, and sort them into a sequence that works?
Whats the best/most efficient manner in which to approach this?

-- Original Question Title: Random Quadrilateral Generation

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the fact that if you take 3 random points, they will always form a convex, non-intersecting triangle (provided the points are all different). Then you can just pop out one of the edges by adding a fourth point a random distance along the last edge, and pushing it away from the center of the triangle by a random amount.

- Start off by generating a random triangle by generating 3 random points: A, B, C
- Choose a random number between 0 and 1, and use it to calculate a point D somewhere along the line between C and A
- Calculate the centroid of the triangle by averaging A, B, C
- Calculate another random number between 1 and n (say 2)
- Calculate the vector from the centroid to D (subtract the centroid from D), and multiply it by this second random number, then add back to the centroid. This will produce your fourth point.

I'm not sure if you have any aesthetic requirements (e.g. no excessively pointy shapes) but you could play around with the random number generation a bit to get the results you like. For example in the second step you could choose a random number between 0.2 and 0.8, for example, so the points aren't too close together. You can also change the value of n in the fourth step.

Another issue is winding. With this method, half the quads will have a clockwise winding and have will be counter-clockwise. If you need a particular winding you can do a winding test (sign of dot product of BC with normal of AB), and if it's not the way you want then just reflect all the points on one axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your points from the perimeter of a circle all the vertices will be convex.

Knowing this we can program a loop to branch out to a non-existant circle and generate corners that'll always produce a convex shape.

```
angles=[];
for (var i = 4; i--;) angles.push(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
```

Now the angles need to be sorted so when the shape is created, clockwise, they're chosen in order of angle size.
This will stop points crossing / self intersection of the shape.

```
angles.sort()
```

Now you can create the shape using the triganometric functions `cos` and `sin`, these will convert the angle to actual co-ordinates.

```
polygon([
    vector(Math.cos(angles[0]), Math.sin(angles[0])),
    vector(Math.cos(angles[1]), Math.sin(angles[1])),
    vector(Math.cos(angles[2]), Math.sin(angles[2])),
    vector(Math.cos(angles[3]), Math.sin(angles[3]))
]);`
```